# Installing and running a guest OS on KVM-qemu with only serial console access

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, console, qemu, serial

I am trying to installing a bsd distro with virt-installer. With a Linux distro I used this:

```
virt-install -n debian -r 1024 --vcpus=1 --accelerate -v --disk /var/kvm/installation-disks/debian.img,size=6--nographics
--network=bridge:br0,model=ne2k_pci,mac=52:54:00:66:68:09 -l http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-amd64/current/images/
-x console=ttyS0,115200
```

This loads the installer directly from the online mirror. With Fedora I used this mirror: http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/x86_64/os/

Are there such mirrors for freebsd or openbsd?

The reason I want direct installable ftp/http mirrors is because I can access my physical server only via ssh, and it doesn't have a X server or a window manager to give me a VNC GUI.

When I tried installing centos 6 with an online mirror I was able to finish the installation via serial console, but after I rebooted it, the serial console never worked for me. I tried everything possible---editing `menu.lst`, `inttab` and `securtty` files.

Fedora 16 booted fine from serial console, but got stuck when it loaded anaconda installer.

I tried editing freebsd iso installation media by adding serial console option to boot option. And installation was successful. But couldn't boot into it becuase it wasn't giving console acess. I couldn't edit any files as `ufs` partition cannot be loaded with write access on my Ubuntu server 10.04.

Only debian squeeze worked well, it worked for me even without editing a single configuration file.

I want to have CLI versions of fedora/centos and freebsd/openbsd. But, looks like there isn't any hope for me to have them, as I have to depend on a serial console to do everything.

Comment: Did you try to install virt-manager on your local machine and add a remote connection over SSH?  This should give you access to VM consoles without any need to install X on the server itself (just netcat needs to be installed on the server to perform socket redirection).

Answer (score 0):

After installation try `guestfish --rw -i -d debian` and edit the menu.lst file and add `console=ttyS0` to kernel args. I also needed to add `ttyS0` to `/etc/securetty` to enable shell on the serial console.